# Switching Off Sound in an iPhone Application

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can someone  please tell me how to switch off sound in an iPhone Application. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view controller that plays your sounds, add an ivar with a @property

```
BOOL muteSoundFlag // as ivar of view controller
@property (nonatomic, retain) BOOL muteSound; // in header
@synthesize muteSound; // in implementation
```

Wrap all your sound playing code in an if...block

```
if (!self.muteSoundFlag) {
    // your sound player code
}
```

When you want sound muted, set the flag to true

self.muteSoundFlag = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about stopping any currently playing music when your application is launched?  You can have the music fade out when your app is launched by setting the audio category for media playback.  Add the code below to your applicationDidFinishLaunching method in the app delegate.

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, self);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

Comment: Hey...Thanks for the reply...Actually, I am looking for a way to mute the sounds in my application :). Can you please help me with it

Comment: The sound your application plays or sounds the system might play?

Comment: Thanks Greg. It is just the sound my application plays :)